# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake : IO.bundle

Tags: macos, perl, io, dyld

I made a simple bioperl script using the following libraries

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Bio::SeqIO;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Std;
```

- It used to work but since some perl updates it fails with:

  dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake
    Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/IO/IO.bundle
    Expected in: flat namespace

  dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_xs_handshake
    Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/IO/IO.bundle
    Expected in: flat namespace

- I use macport and sometimes cpan (maybe not so good idea!!) to maintain my OSX laptop (10.13.5)
- My perl -V gives:

  Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 26 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
      osname=darwin
      osvers=17.6.0
      archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
      uname='darwin highsierra.internal.macports.net 17.6.0 darwin kernel version 17.6.0: tue may 8 15:22:16 pdt 2018; root:xnu-4570.61.1~1release_x86_64 x86_64 '
      config_args='-des -Dprefix=/opt/local -Dscriptdir=/opt/local/bin -Dvendorprefix=/opt/local -Dusemultiplicity=y -Dusethreads -Duseshrplib -Dcc=/usr/bin/clang -Dman1ext=1pm -Dman3ext=3pm -Dinstallstyle=lib/perl5 -Dman1dir=/opt/local/share/man/man1p -Dman3dir=/opt/local/share/man/man3p -Dsitebin=/opt/local/libexec/perl5.26/sitebin -Dsiteman1dir=/opt/local/share/perl5.26/siteman/man1 -Dsiteman3dir=/opt/local/share/perl5.26/siteman/man3 -Dvendorbin=/opt/local/libexec/perl5.26 -Dvendorman1dir=/opt/local/share/perl5.26/man/man1 -Dvendorman3dir=/opt/local/share/perl5.26/man/man3 -Dpager=/usr/bin/less -sR -Dperlpath=/opt/local/bin/perl5.26 -Dstartperl=#!/opt/local/bin/perl5.26 -Acppflags=-I/opt/local/include -Accflags=-pipe -Os  -Alddlflags=-L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -Aldflags=-L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names '
      hint=recommended
      useposix=true
      d_sigaction=define
      useithreads=define
      usemultiplicity=define
      use64bitint=define
      use64bitall=define
      uselongdouble=undef
      usemymalloc=n
      default_inc_excludes_dot=define
      bincompat5005=undef
    Compiler:
      cc='/usr/bin/clang'
      ccflags ='-fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -pipe -Os  -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -I/opt/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV'
      optimize='-O3'
      cppflags='-I/opt/local/include -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -pipe -Os  -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -I/opt/local/include'
      ccversion=''
      gccversion='4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)'
      gccosandvers=''
      intsize=4
      longsize=8
      ptrsize=8
      doublesize=8
      byteorder=12345678
      doublekind=3
      d_longlong=define
      longlongsize=8
      d_longdbl=define
      longdblsize=16
      longdblkind=3
      ivtype='long'
      ivsize=8
      nvtype='double'
      nvsize=8
      Off_t='off_t'
      lseeksize=8
      alignbytes=8
      prototype=define
    Linker and Libraries:
      ld='/usr/bin/clang'
      ldflags =' -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -fstack-protector-strong'
      libpth=/opt/local/lib /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/lib /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib /usr/lib
      libs=-lpthread -lgdbm -ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
      perllibs=-lpthread -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
      libc=
      so=dylib
      useshrplib=true
      libperl=libperl.dylib
      gnulibc_version=''
    Dynamic Linking:
      dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs
      dlext=bundle
      d_dlsymun=undef
      ccdlflags=' '
      cccdlflags=' '
      lddlflags=' -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -fstack-protector-strong'

  Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
    Compile-time options:
      HAS_TIMES
      MULTIPLICITY
      PERLIO_LAYERS
      PERL_COPY_ON_WRITE
      PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
      PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
      PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
      PERL_OP_PARENT
      PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
      PERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV
      USE_64_BIT_ALL
      USE_64_BIT_INT
      USE_ITHREADS
      USE_LARGE_FILES
      USE_LOCALE
      USE_LOCALE_COLLATE
      USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
      USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC
      USE_LOCALE_TIME
      USE_PERLIO
      USE_PERL_ATOF
      USE_REENTRANT_API
    Built under darwin
    Compiled at Jun 19 2018 13:45:49
    %ENV:
      PERL5LIB="/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26::/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/bioperl-1.2.3:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/bioperl-live:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl/modules:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-compara/modules:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-variation/modules:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-functgenomics/modules:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-external/modules:/opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-tools/modules:/opt/biotools/circos/lib:/opt/biotools/circosapi/lib:/opt/biotools/GeneNomenclatureUtils/modules:/opt/biotools/Haplotyping-0.1.0/Perl:/opt/biotools/hmmer/PfamScan:/opt/biotools/kaviar:/opt/biotools/pita/lib:/opt/biotools/vcftools/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24:/work/MyScripts/modules:/work/MyScripts/pharmgkb:/opt/biotools/mummer/scripts"
    @INC:
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/bioperl-1.2.3
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/bioperl-live
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl/modules
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-compara/modules
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-variation/modules
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-functgenomics/modules
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-external/modules
      /opt/biotools/ensembl_main/ensembl-tools/modules
      /opt/biotools/circos/lib
      /opt/biotools/circosapi/lib
      /opt/biotools/GeneNomenclatureUtils/modules
      /opt/biotools/Haplotyping-0.1.0/Perl
      /opt/biotools/hmmer/PfamScan
      /opt/biotools/kaviar
      /opt/biotools/pita/lib
      /opt/biotools/vcftools/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24
      /work/MyScripts/modules
      /work/MyScripts/pharmgkb
      /opt/biotools/mummer/scripts
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level
      /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.26

I suspect I changed some path or dependency but do not find what.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: “some perl updates” – could you clarify? If you upgrade your perl (e.g. from 5.24.x to 5.26.x) then you should reinstall all your modules, at least those modules with compiled (XS) extensions. E.g. your `@INC` paths still contain `/opt/biotools/vcftools/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24 /work/MyScripts/modules` which might be a problem.

Comment: This error happens when you load an XS module that was installed with a different build of Perl than the one loading it.

Comment: @amon, the vcftools module should be OK as it is not related to this error and MyScripts only contains my own modules which are too simple to be the cause. For other modules compiled from older perl versions, is there a way to systematically recompile them? Thanks for any help

Comment: thanks to both, it was a PERL5LIB I added as  PERL5LIB=/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26:${PERL5LIB} that was confusing the system.